# finding probability of X and Y by given joint PMF

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let random variables X and Y have the joint PMF $\mathsf p_{X,Y} (x,y)$ given below.

$$\mathsf p_{X,Y} (x,y) = \begin{cases}0.05 & : x=1,2,3,4 \land y=1,2,3,4\\
                    0 & :\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Let A denote the event that max$(X,Y) < 3$. Find the conditional PMF $\mathsf p_{X,Y|A} (x,y)$.

This is the question I asked. I have missed some lecture, so I have to learn it by myself, I need to learn this probability of $X$ and $Y$  ( $\mathsf p_{X,Y} (x,y)$ ) If you guys give me some good examples (near to life or can be imaginable examples) i would really appreciate.

Comment: You need some restriction on $Y$, for example with it taking five possible values such as $0,1,2,3,4$ or $1,2,3,4,5$, so that the total probability is $1$, e.g. $0.05\times 4 \times 5$

Comment: I could make guesses about the values of $y$ for which the formula holds. However, these were undoubtedly specified in the problem, there were $5$ of them. Like Henry, I would guess it said $y=0$ to $4$ or $y=1$ to $5$. Some details of the answer will depend on the allowed values of $y$.

Comment: now i give restriction on $Y$

Comment: @Henry Can you explain now?

Comment: @Andy, that is still not a valid pmf.  The total probability does not equal 1.

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes I also wondering why but question is this :(

Comment: Maybe they corrected the question at the lecture you missed?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the definition of conditional probability and the law of total probability
$\begin{align}
\mathsf p_{X,Y\mid A}(x,y)
 & = \mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y\cap \max(X,Y)<3)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y\cap \max(x,y)<3)}{\mathsf P(\max(X,Y)<3)}
\\[2ex]
 & = \dfrac{
  \mathsf p_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\operatorname{\bf 1}_{\max(x,y) < 3}
}{
  \mathop{\sum\sum}\limits_{k,h\mid\max(k,h) < 3}\,\mathsf p_{X,Y}(k,h)
}
\\[1ex]
 & = \begin{cases}
 \mathsf p_{X,Y}(x,y)\big/(\mathop{\sum\sum}\limits_{k,h\mid\max(k,h) < 3}\,\mathsf p_{X,Y}(k,h))
 & :\max(x,y)<3, (x,y)\in\{...\}
 \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}
 \end{cases}
\end{align}$

**Note**, to continue you will need the correct support and probability mass for $\mathsf p_{X,Y}$, which isn't what you have given in the original post (as the total probability of that does not sum to 1).